# Installing Python modules for QGIS 3 on Mac

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, installation, mac

I want to install some third-party Python modules for QGIS 3 on Mac, however, I have no clue how to do it, since I am not so much familiar with different Python environments.

Is there any similar thing to the OSGeo4W Shell on Mac, or is it possible to do via the terminal?

Comment: I ended up building the packages in another python and copying them into /Applications/QGIS3.14.app/Contents/Resources/python. Nasty.

Comment: I tried all the suggestions here without effort...

Answer (score 6):

from [Download for Macos](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)

> These packages use the python.org Python 3, version 3.6, the "macosx10.9" build - other distributions are not supported. Install Python before installing QGIS.

1) To know the python interpreter path used by QGIS

In the Python console of QGIS

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

2) then in the terminal

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3.6
Python 3.6.8 
...
>>>
```

3) and you can install third-party Python modules from the terminal

```
/usr/local/python/bin/python3.6 -m pip install shapely
```

or

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 setup.py install
```

#### New

I cannot install the 3.10 version in my Mac, but if I examine the application file:

The content of   /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/

The QGIS executable is here

[image]

In the  /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/bin folder

[image]

There is a  symbolic link file  python3 that points to /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. When I run the command sys.executable from my python console I get the following link: /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS, and when I type it in the terminal then QGIS3 just opens.  Is there an alternative python command to find the path to the python environment?

Comment: In the Python console of QGIS ? (because /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS is the executable of QGIS, not of Python) -> see New above

Comment: It still doesn't work for me when I enter these directories and type python -m pip install 'package'.  It's like the python that is being called is the default python installed on Mac and not the python installed in the QGIS3 environment...              Is there a terminal command to make sure that the python and pip called is the one running in QGIS3, and not the other one (though the versions are the same)?

Comment: The one running in QGIS3 is the sys.executable result in the QGIS3 Python console (the default python installed on Mac is version 2.x)

Comment: I remember that I had once changed the main python of the mac from 2 to 3, but how do I call the one in the python console from the terminal?

Comment: I cant seem to work this out either. Easy to do windows and linux, just cant seem to work out on osx

Answer (score 4):

Tested on QGIS 3.14 under MacOSX 10.15.

In QGIS, go to menu Settings > System and search for **Environment** options:

[image]

Check the <kbd>Use custom variables</kbd> checkbox, and :

- In the <kbd>Apply</kbd> column, choose `Append` ;
- In the <kbd>Variable</kbd> column, write `PYTHONPATH` ;
- In the <kbd>Value</kbd> column, write the path to the directory with python modules as `:/Users/me/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages`

Beware, to correctly separate environment variables, don't forget the colon.

Restart QGIS and in the QGIS Python console, try to import your module.

Comment: I did as you suggested and pointed to a conda env's site-packages. Still get an ImportError Library not loaded. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

For Windows users, the answers above are probably still fine, but for MacOS users who don't want to re-point their `PYTHONPATH` to an external Python, this answer has changed slightly for the bundled Python distribution in recent QGIS packages for MacOS.

The `pip3` command is now found here after a default install (adjacent to the bundled `python`):

```
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pip3
```

If you open a terminal and type (for example to install `ptvsd`):

```
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pip3 install ptvsd
```

you should get the result you're hoping for.

You can verify the library was installed in your Python library repository here:

```
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python/site-packages
```

(I have not added this a comment because I don't really use this platform and don't have the minimum rep.)