# QGIS 3.18.2: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'supy'

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins

starting QGIS I get the error:

> Konnte Erweiterung 'processing_umep' nicht laden aufgrund eines
> Fehlers beim Aufruf der classFactory() Methode
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'supy'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
> line 335, in _startPlugin
>
> plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>
> :
>
> :
>
> etc

But when I try to install supy

> sudo -H pip install supy

I am informed that supy is already installed and that all "Requirement already satisfied".

What can I do?

---

Python-Version: 3.8.7 (default, Feb 10 2021, 09:04:08) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)]

QGIS-Version: 3.18.2-Zürich Zürich, 44d7dfabbe

OS: macOS Big Sur 11.3.1

Comment: Have a look at how to install python dependencies for QGIS on Mac: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351280/installing-python-modules-for-qgis-3-on-mac

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Yesterday I tried the suggestions found in your link, but in the end the error messages remain...